# correct set up for fitting binomial data in GLM

Tags: r, regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, binary-data

I have the following data and am trying to fit a glm model. There are six factors. Each factor has $250$ samples and $Y$ accounts for the successes.

```
X <- seq(1:6); n = rep(250, 6)
Y <- c(28, 53, 93, 126, 172, 197)
```

I have the following model if I create a vector that follows the success and fail.

```
y <- cbind(Y, n - Y)
mod <- glm(y ~ X, family = binomial())
summary(mod)
```

If I build a model in binary classification style, I surely have a different model.

```
temp_y <- c()
temp_X <- c()
for(i in c(1:6)) {
  temp <- rep(0, 250)
  temp_X <- c(temp_X, rep(i, 250))
  temp[1:Y[i]] <- 1
  temp_y <- c(temp_y, temp)
}

mod2 <- glm(temp_y ~ as.factor(temp_X), family = binomial())
summary(mod2)
```

Which one is the correct setup?

Comment: The only difference between these models is that you provided `X` as a categorical predictor with 6 levels in one and as a continuous covariate in the other.